# What is the difference between "clinician" and "therapist"?

Tags: terminology, clinical-study, therapy

I am reading the book *Mindfulness and Psychotherapy*, and at first I thought *clinician* and *therapist* are used interchangeably, but it seems not. So is there any difference between the two? If yes, is this difference only limited in psychotherapy, or does this happen on other fields as well (e.g. physiotherapy)?

> The integration of mindfulness into cognitive-behavioral therapy has led to new mindfulness exercises and multicomponent treatment protocols. These mindfulness-based psychotherapies involve teaching patients specific mindfulness skills, such as breath awareness, mindful eating, and other ways of regulating attention. The proliferation of treatment protocols is encouraging **clinicians** to experiment with mindfulness techniques, even if **therapists** do not implement the entire protocol.

<sup>Related: [Clinician - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinician)</sup>

Comment: This is probably better suited to CogSci

Comment: I know, but as I ask for general therapy, including non-psychotherapy, I think it's better suited to ask here

Comment: The text is from a psychology book. The term "therapist" is used in psychology, but in the medical field it is not usually used outside of massage therapy or physical/occupational/speech therapy.

Comment: Yes. They are also "clinicians", is that correct? So what is the difference between the terms?